# Handling & symbol in filename

Tags: linux, scripting, ksh

There is a "&" symbol in one of the files' name.

If I try to use `mv` command, I'm not able to correctly get the file name.

Actual filename :

```
abc&def.xls
```

`mv` command:

```
 mv $home/abc&def.xls $enter/abc&def.xls
```

But I'm getting an error like this :

---

> mv : missing file destination operand after $home/abc

---

Please suggest how to go ahead with moving the file to different destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just escaped the ampersand and it worked:

```
mv abc\&def.xls ..
```

Good luck